# Unable to update or delete a product

Tags: catalog

I have several thousands of items that are currently disabled. I'm now trying to delete them via the Catalog > Products page but I get an error message for some of the products. 
I cannot make any changes to these products. Even just saving the part I get a 'No Such Entity' message.
I have manually whittled the list of parts from over 10000 to about 1300 and I get an error if I try to do anything with them.
I am on Magento version 2.2.6.
I'm a newbie on here and with Magento 2 so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Error message when using the catalog page to try and delete the part.
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): Unable to remove product EVBCONCEWHC3

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException): Unable to remove product EVBCONCEWHC3
#0 /var/www/vhosts/toolstoyou.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository/Interceptor.php(63):
```

Comment: Please run 'php bin/magento indexer:reindex' command and check. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please run `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and `php bin/magento cache:flush` command.

Then change or delete your product.

I hope it will help you.